# Strange behavior of Membership.GetUser() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have this code:

```
 public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //I added this just to check if it returns true.
            bool check = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                //trying to get get the name here.
                string name = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {                        
                        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
                        switch (roles[0])
                        {
                            case "Employee":
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
                            case "HR_Team":
                                return Redirect("");
                            case "Team_Lead":
                                return Redirect("");
                            case "Management":
                                return Redirect("");
                        }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
```

The code was working absolutely fine but I don't know why it stopped responding properly. Now I'm not able to get the user name as well as it's role (that's probably because it's not getting the username I guess). I've no idea at all how it happened. Somebody please help getting rid of this problem. I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have specified the username when getting the user because you have not yet set the forms authentication cookie (only after you redirect you will be able to use this overload that doesn't take any argument).

Also what's the point of calling `Membership.GetUser().UserName;` when you already have the username in `model.UserName`?

Same thing stands for the roles:

```
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName);
```

Don't attempt to use `User.Identity.Name` in your LogOn method because you don't have an authenticated user yet.

And if you wanted to get the user use:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
```

instead of:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
```

Comment: Awesome, you rock Sir Darin Dimitrov. Thanks a lot.
Also, "@User.Identity.Name" in razor view returns null even after successful login. can you please help.
thanks again :)